# Add validation to a shared class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple class that is shared. I have DataAnnotations to show required fields

```
public class Address
{
    [Required]
    public string Contact { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    public string Company{ get; set; }
}
```

In one instance where this class is used I need to make Company required. What is the best way to make Company only required when needed.

The Address object is being used in other classes such as Order, Account etc.

Comment: Interfaces and constructors.  Personally I'd do a different constructor that requires the parameter, and one where it has a default value.

Comment: https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations has a nice RequiredIf Attribute that you could hook up to a boolean property on the Address class.  Set the boolean to true when you need to require the Company and leave it false when you don't require it.

Comment: Ahhh, view models. Don't try to reuse every single class you write in every possible context :-)

Comment: You can use [MetadataTypeAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)